Select sibling node value based on multiple sibling conditions not using an xpath string
There are various answers to finding an xml node using xpath like here. In python using lxml, is there a more pythonic way of building this condition list? I know I can build the xpath string using an f-string but maybe there is a more elegant way.
As example:
root.xpath('//Group/Person[Position = "CEO" and Street = "Main" and Name = "Paul"]/Condition[Group = "Manager"]/Room')[0].text

can be built like so:
root.xpath(f'//Group/Person[Position = "{role}" and Street = "{street}" and Name = "{name}"]/Condition[Group = "{group}"]/Room')[0].text

but it still looks clumsy.

That way of doing it also leaves you exposed to errors if variables like street and name contain quotation marks - which means it also leaves you exposed to injection attacks. XPath itself allows you to use variables (Name=$name) but I don't know if the Python XPath API provides any way of setting them.

Besides injection risk, what do find "clumsy" about the parameterized XPath?  What would your ideal "elegant" solution look like?

Yes, you can set parameters for XPath, here is an example for both lxml and SaxonC 12:
from lxml import etree

from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

xml = '''<root>
  <item>
    <name>foo</name>
    <value>bar</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>bar</name>
    <value>foo</value>
  </item>
</root>'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)

name = 'bar'

print(root.xpath('item[name = $name]', name=name))

with PySaxonProcessor() as saxon_proc:
    xpath_proc = saxon_proc.new_xpath_processor()

    xpath_proc.set_context(xdm_item=saxon_proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml))

    xpath_proc.set_parameter('name', saxon_proc.make_string_value(name))

    print(xpath_proc.evaluate('root/item[name = $name]'))


Thanks. Since saxonc is a commercial product I'll stick to a lxml solution.

saxonche is a product of Saxonica but you can find it on PyPi like lxml e.g. https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/. As long as you only need XPath 1.0 of course lxml is sufficient but you don't have to pay any license fees to use saxonche and XPath 3.1 or XSLT 3.0, if that is what your comment is supposed to indicate with "commercial" (which is the term used there for saxoncpe and saxoncee, not for saxonche).

I'll use this in my company and want to avoid diving into licence issues. Thanks anyway. With root.xpath(f'item[name = {name}]') being equivalent to root.xpath('item[name = $name]', name=name) I'll stay where I am.

@Fred, it is not equivalent as you can inject code with the Python string template while you can't do that if you cleanly use an XPath parameter/variable. But use what you prefer.
